# Is it possible to use a for-loop to create radio buttons?

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, arraylist, hashmap

I'm designing a program that uses an input file to store colors and their hexadecimal value(for example, Black 000000).  Currently I have two arraylists, one for colors and one for hex value (I know I should probably use a map but I'm stuck with getting input transferred into the map).  Is there anyway to use a for-loop using the size of my colorCollection array?  I've attached some code to see if that helps what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ReadStoreShow extends JFrame{
private static int number;
private static ArrayList<String> colorCollection = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<String> hexCollection = new ArrayList<String>();
private JRadioButton[] jrbColor = new JRadioButton[20];

public ReadStoreShow() {
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,5));
    for (int i = 0; i < colorCollection.size(); i++) {
        jrbColor[i] = new JRadioButton(colorCollection.get(i));
            // Is it possible to create buttons based on the size of colorCollection?
        jrbColor[i].setText(colorCollection.get(i));
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(jrbColor[i]);
        p1.add(jrbColor[]);
        } 

        add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setContentPane(p1);
        for (int j = 0; j < colorCollection.size(); j++){
        jrbColor[j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
                public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                for (int k = 0; k < colorCollection.size(); k++){
                    final String hexColor = hexCollection.get(k);
                    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode(hexColor));
                    repaint();
                }
                } 
            });
        }
}

public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final ReadStoreShow frame = new ReadStoreShow();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(20, 1));
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setTitle("Color Change");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

try {
     final java.io.File colors = new java.io.File("input.txt");
     final Scanner input = new Scanner(colors);
     while (input.hasNext()) {
         colorCollection.add(input.next());
         hexCollection.add(input.next());
     } // I'm assuming I should have used one Map instead of two arrays...
     input.close();
 }
 catch (final FileNotFoundException a) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found.");
     System.exit(0);
 }
while (number < 10 || number > 20) {
     number = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
         "How many colors do you want? Must be between 10 and 20."));
 } // while
 System.out.println("The colors entered were:");
 for (final Iterator<String> itr = colorCollection.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
     System.out.println(itr.next());
 System.out.println("The hexidecimal codes entered were:");
 for (final Iterator<String> itr = hexCollection.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
     System.out.println(itr.next());
 }
}
```

Here is my current input.txt:

```
Black 0x000000 
Red 0xFF0000
Green 0x00FF00
Blue 0x0000FF
Yellow 0xFFFF00
White 0xFFFFFF 
Gray 0x707070
Purple 0x990099
Orange 0xFF6600
LightBlue 0x6666FF
```

Comment: FYI, I know this isn't the question you asked, but: you rarely need to use an iterator directly, like you did at the end of your program.  `for (String s : colorCollection)` (which wasn't in the first few versions of Java) is the easy way to do it.

Comment: @ajb Thanks for the tip!  I changed it in my program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this, but you have a lot of issues in your code. I'm describing just a few below, and there's more info in the comments here.

You have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < colorCollection.size(); i++) {
    jrbColor[i] = new JRadioButton(colorCollection.get(i));
    ...
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(jrbColor[i]);
}
```

Here you are creating a new `ButtonGroup` for every radio button. This probably isn't what you want. A `ButtonGroup` is a group of radio buttons in which selection is mutually exclusive, so your `ButtonGroup` should contain all the options for a given conceptual choice. In your case, it sounds like simply:

```
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
for (int i = 0; i < colorCollection.size(); i++) {
    jrbColor[i] = new JRadioButton(colorCollection.get(i));
    ...
    group.add(jrbColor[i]);
}
```

Another issue is you are using a fixed size `JRadioButton[]` array. Consider using something dynamic, like an [`ArrayList<JRadioButton>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead. That way you can just keep adding as many new buttons as you want to the end of it.

The third thing that sticks out at me is, you don't want to `setContentPane(p1)`; Swing will provide a content pane for you. All you need to do is set an appropriate layout and add your components to the frame.

There is a huge collection of official swing tutorials [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). I suggest browsing through and reading the relevant ones; in particular, the ones on [radio buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), [button groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html), and [laying out components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) will be very helpful for you.

Instead of directly addressing all the issues in your snippet; you may want to go through those tutorials, give it another shot, then come back if you're still having issues. It might also help if you start with a small test program to play around with that just creates a few radio buttons on a panel; that way you can get a feel for it without getting tied down by everything else your actual program is supposed to be doing.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply.  The actual issue I'm seeing is that my panel just pops up with no buttons in it.  I've been banging my head for hours trying to figure out what is going on. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: No dice :(  I'll have to play around with it in an hour, my eyes are killing after staring at this all day.  I really appreciate your pointers, I'll have to check out those tutorials.  I'm sure I'm just missing something so easy.

Comment: @JasonC Swing components, with the exception of windows based classes (including `JInternalFrame`) are visible by default...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Right; Thanks. I'm not thinking clearly right now. I also shouldn't have answered without analyzing the code more closely. This is not my finest work...

Comment: You're 99% of the way there.  The line `p1.add(jrbColor[]);` is wrong and should be `p1.add(jrbColor[i]);` which should solve the problem...

Comment: Oh and `colorCollection.size()` is `0` when the frame's constructor is called :P - Meaning that there is nothing for the constructor to add to the frame, hence no output...

Comment: @JasonC  i don't remember since what java version, if you `add` directly to the jframe it's like adding to the contentPane

Comment: @JasonC `As a conveniance add and its variants, remove and setLayout have been overridden to forward to the contentPane as necessary. This means you can write:

       frame.add(child); And the child will be added to the contentPane.`

Comment: Thanks for being on the look out, guys.

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you both for helping out with this!  I got everything up and running except assigning colors to the buttons when pressed.  Tried knocking it out with a for-loop but no dice tonight.  I'll have to come back to it tomorrow. (fyi, I actually changed where I was adding my frame in the code and that is what finally got my buttons to show up... hehe... always something easy.)